# Different versions of libssl used by c++ packages, error " multiple definition of `SSL_ first defined here" (gRPC)

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, openssl, grpc

I have a private c++ library with access only to the header files, I am trying to use the package along with gRPC for remote calls.

**PROBLEM:**

gRPC uses a newer version of libssl and libcrypto.
Where as the private library uses a older version.

When i try to compile grpc along with the private library i get the following error when i execute make.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o): in function `SSL_clear':
ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x2b0): multiple definition of `SSL_clear'; /home/user/.local/lib/libssl.a(ssl_lib.cc.o):ssl_lib.cc:(.text+0x8778): first defined here
```

> /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a is the verion required by the private library

> /home/user/.local/lib/libssl.a is the version required by gRPC.

How would i go about to solve this issue.
Since the private library uses a specific version of openssl (1.0.2s), which is not compatible with gRPC

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but what is your question?

Comment: Hey @SamVarshavchik, I have edited the question to give you more context

Comment: There is no easy way to use multiple versions of the same library. The only practical way to do that is NOT to link with the alternate shared library directly, but rather `dlopen` it, use `dlsym` to resolve symbols from that library and call it directly. And, of course, there is absolutely no chance, whatsoever that you can do things like, for example, open SSL connections using one version of the library, and expect the other one to use it.